# Contextualization in ASP.NET C# or Javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net

Wondering if anyone knows of any open source code about contextualization via JS (javascript) or ASP.NET ? That is, contextualization of content - determining "what" content is?

Its an interesting area and I cant seem to find any previous projects on it ?

Really appreciate any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you are looking to build something like a search engine that can find a relevant document in a sea of nondescript documents which do not contain any metadata, only their textual content.

Computers are notoriously bad at this kind of categorization, for the same reasons that they can identify spelling, but not grammar errors.  It's a pattern matching problem that relies on human context to determine the correct solution.

Google is good at this because it relies on human behaviors to create relevance (like how many links from other sites a page has).

The closest thing I can think of that will do what you want (without actually attaching genuine metadata to each document by hand) is full text search.  The [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_text_search) article has several references to software that does this.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do, it may be easier to mine your page for context after the conent has been rendered.  That way you are ensured that you have the context that the user is viewing the page.  Here is a post to a jQuery plugin that [highlights target words on a html page](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html).

Here are some other plugins you might want to review:

- [quickSearch plugin](http://rikrikrik.com/jquery/quicksearch/)
- [QuickSilver Search plugin](http://orderedlist.com/demos/quicksilverjs/jquery.html)